# Store Thunderbird emails in external hard drive (Ethernet) and let client machine read from there

Tags: external-hard-drive, thunderbird, ubuntu-12.04

Is it possible to do that? I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Alternatively, could I install Thunderbird in that drive so as the emails be considered as "local" files, and then let each machine lunch its own instance of Thunderbird? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is [here](http://portableapps.com/support/thunderbird_portable).  My recommendation is that you use portable Thunderbird so that your files aren't on the machine at all.  This increases your security as well.